# Unlock keyring при авторизации в ос

Tags: linux, archlinux, manjaro

Достало постоянное "Unlock keyring" при авторизации в систему. Ввожу пароль -> вхожу -> и тут же вылазит окно "Unlock keyring", где просить ввести пароль. Как можно убрать это?

```
 ██████████████████  ████████     egor@A840N750TI12G
 ██████████████████  ████████     OS: Manjaro 20.0.1 Lysia
 ██████████████████  ████████     Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.4.39-1-MANJARO
 ██████████████████  ████████     Uptime: 7m
 ████████            ████████     Packages: 1486
 ████████  ████████  ████████     Shell: bash 5.0.16
 ████████  ████████  ████████     Resolution: 3200x1080
 ████████  ████████  ████████     DE: KDE 5.69.0 / Plasma 5.18.5
 ████████  ████████  ████████     WM: KWin
 ████████  ████████  ████████     GTK Theme: Sweet [GTK3]
 ████████  ████████  ████████     Icon Theme: candy-icons
 ████████  ████████  ████████     Disk: 165G / 434G (40%)
 ████████  ████████  ████████     CPU: AMD Athlon X4 840 Quad Core @ 4x 3.1GHz
 ████████  ████████  ████████     GPU: GeForce GTX 750 Ti
                                  RAM: 4512MiB / 12010MiB
```

Comment: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/unlock-keyring-for-google-chrome/85340

Comment: Похоже что это фича кде-шной манджары. Я в xfce такого никогда не наблюдал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установи `seahorse`. На "Пароли" - "Вход" правой кнопкой - сменить пароль. Введите старый и 2 раза пустой. Тогда связка паролей не будет спрашивать пароль.

Лучше конечно удалить пакет `gnome-keyring` потому что у KDE есть другой менеджер паролей

Чтоб использовать `gnome-keyring` с паролем от входа в систему нужно чтоб в `/etc/pam.d/` в нужном профиле (не помню как называется kdeшный) были строчки

```
auth     optional  pam_gnome_keyring.so
password optional  pam_gnome_keyring.so use_authtok
session  optional  pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
```

Если это окно не от gnome-keyring, то надо проверить pam